# Axis2 what is the correct way to set connection timeout and so timeout

Tags: java, apache-axis

I have a Java program which use Axis2 for consuming a web service. Now I want to set connection timeout and socket timeout for that client.

I have searched and found that there are two possible ways to do that.

**1st method**

https://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/how-to-configure-timeout-duration-at-client-side-for-axis2-web-services/

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, new Integer(timeOutInMilliSeconds));
```

**2nd method**

https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-44893

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
HttpConnectionManagerParams params = new HttpConnectionManagerParams();
params.setSoTimeout(timeOutInMilliSeconds);
params.setConnectionTimeout(timeOutInMilliSeconds);
multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.setParams(params);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
stub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getConfigurationContext().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, httpClient);
```

Does anyone know what is the difference between those two methods?

**Edit** : 
Also I have found the following method which is used to set timeout. Confusion at it's best. :(

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(180000);
```

Comment: The 1st sets he connection timeout, the 2nd sets he timeout for the connection pool: Axis uses a pool of 2 connections to make the HTTP requests.

Comment: Why would there be any difference? A connect timeout is a connect timeout, and a read timeout is still a read timeout.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I have already changed the default connection count from 2 to 20 by `setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost` and `setMaxTotalConnections` methods. So is there any functional difference between setting timeout for connection and connection pool?

Comment: The 1st method worked fine for me. This is some off topic. But thank you @Chathura, i've had a problem with this for a while now becouse i diden't get stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(180000);  to work.